# Angular 11 won't update the UI

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

One of my Angular 11 components won't update the UI and I have no idea anymore - why or where my mistake happened. As far as I can see I did everything as 1000-time before, but...

The method `identify()` is triggered by a button-click. It loads two very large lists of objects via a REST-API from the server. The REST-API calls are tested and work as expected. The elements from the loaded lists are compared to each other and a counter `precessed` is increased.
The console output works fine, BUT the UI is not updated. I tried also `ApplicationRef.tick()` and all other method to force an update or the UI. Nothing worked.

An output is only written to the UI after the `foreach` loop is ended.

Long words - short story: this are the simplified code fragments:

**Service**

```js
    loadPrebenSkaters(): Observable<PrebenSkater[]> {
        return this.restService.get('/preben/skaters/preben/all').pipe(map((response: any) => response.map((item: any) => new PrebenSkater(item))));
    }

    loadSsnSkaters(): Observable<SsnSkater[]> {
        return this.restService.get('/preben/skaters/ssn/all/').pipe(map((response: any) => response.map((item: any) => new SsnSkater(item))));
    }
```

**Component**

```js
    identify() {
        this.service.loadPrebenSkaters().subscribe((prebenList: PrebenSkater[]) => {
            this.service.loadSsnSkaters().subscribe((ssnlist: SsnSkater[]) => {
                ssnlist.forEach((ssn: SsnSkater) => {
                    let found: string[] = prebenList.filter(preben => ...).map(item => item.fullname);

                    if (found.length) {
                        ssn.uuid = found;
                        this.processed++;
                    } else {
                        this.processed++;
                    }

                    if (this.processed % 10 == 0) {
                        console.log(this.processed);
                    }

                    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

**HTML**

```html
    <button (click)="identify()">Global Identify</button>
    <span class="pr-4">Identified: {{ processed }}</span>
```

Is there any mistake I can't see?

Comment: forEach run quickly .Ui will update after that.Do you expect the ui update to look like an animation ?

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha I'd like to update the UI inside the loop. forEach runs quick, but the entire process of the loop takes several minutes.

Comment: you can read about change detection in detail here https://jagjeets.medium.com/using-angular-change-detection-effectively-f69d6a493c35